# What is the origin of the word "doh" (as seen in the world's first crossword puzzle)?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, obscure-terms, biology, plants

The first ever crossword puzzle was written by Arthur Wynne in 1913:

[image: empty crossword grid with clues]

<sub>Image from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:First_crossword.png)</sub>

It has several clues with obscure and obsolete answers, but I was able to find all of them in dictionaries except for this one:

> 10-18. The fibre of the gomuti palm.

The answer is "DOH", as you can confirm from the crossing clues and from countless crossword solution websites that give the answer with no explanation. But I'm not able to find any references of "doh" being used to mean palm fiber outside of this specific puzzle. Every dictionary I search lists only the Homer Simpson interjection or the first note of a musical scale. It is in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arenga_pinnata) for the gomuti palm, but it has only a single mention with no source.

So where does the word come from? Surely it must have appeared in some dictionary or encyclopedia in 1913? Or did Arthur Wynne just make it up and hope no one would notice?

Comment: What a fantastic question all-around !

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I can only find a few citations for this...and most of them are in books *about your crossword*. [One of them](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thinking_Inside_the_Box/k1LXDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=doh%20gomuti&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) says that the clue "would likely be impossible for most non-botanists," and [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Four_letter_Words/3x6PmuQIq-4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=DOH%20palm%20fiber&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover) also references it.

But it wasn't made up, since we can find it in a number of older dictionaries, like [this old Funk & Wagnalls](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Standard_Dictionary_of_the_English_Lan/uQU2AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=doh%20gomuti&pg=RA2-PA542&printsec=frontcover) dictionary, and in [this one](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cyclop%C3%A6dia_of_India_and_of_Eastern_and/qCAAAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=gomuti%20doh&pg=PA127&printsec=frontcover) as well.

Quoting from [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dictionary_of_the_English_Language/PTVCAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=doh%20gomuti&pg=PA434&printsec=frontcover):

> *DÕH*, the name applied in Java, to the fibre of the Ejoo or Gomuti Palm

Per [this journal](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal/Kj5JAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=doh%20fibre%20java&pg=PA455&printsec=frontcover), the original language was Javanese, but I doubt that a more detailed etymology can be easily found.

(There's a *slight* discrepancy in the scientific name given by modern sources and that given by the quoted dictionary; the dictionary says *Arenga Saccharifera* and modern sources call it *Arenga pinnata*, but the two are synonymous according to Wikipedia.)

Comment: Nice finds! It never even occurred to me to try Google Books.

Comment: Any idea why _DÕH_ is capitalized in your definition? Is it an acronym, perhaps? Or is that the standard in this specific dictionary and all words are capitalized in their entries?

Comment: @terdon - that's the standard; they're all capitalized.

Comment: The change in botanical name isn't really a contradiction. Species are renamed relatively frequently. Sometimes because we figure out they were originally assigned to the wrong genus, sometimes because we find out that two things we thought were separate species are actually the same, and one of them gets reclassified as a synonym of the species designation which was officially published first.

Comment: @R.M. - yes, _contradiction_ was probably the wrong word. I still felt it was worth noting in case someone looked at the dictionaries I linked (which use _Saccharifera_) and compared it to other sources. But yes, you're right.

Comment: I think the accents are a pronunciation guide, rather than being part of the spelling.

Comment: What @R.M. said. Synonyms: *Saguerus pinnatus* Wurmb (1779); *Saguerus gamuto* Houtt. (1773); *Borassus gomutus* Lour. (1790); *Arenga saccharifera* Labill. ex DC. (1800); *Gomutus rumphii* Corrêa (1807); *Sagus gomutus* (Lour.) Perr. (1824); *Gomutus saccharifer* (Labill. ex DC.) Spreng. (1825); *Saguerus rumphii* (Corrêa) Roxb. ex Ainslie (1826); *Caryota onusta* Blanco (1837); *Gomutus vulgaris* Oken (1841); *Saguerus saccharifer* (Labill. ex DC.) Blume (1843); *Arenga griffithii* Seem. ex H.Wendl. (1878); *Arenga gamuto* Merr. (1914). Accepted name: *Arenga pinnata* (Wurmb) Merr. (1917)

Answer (score 35):

Adding to [Heartspring’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/607490/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-doh-as-seen-in-the-worlds-first-crossword-puz/607491#607491):

*Doh* appears to be an anglicized rendering of the Javanese *Duk* or *Dok* (Malay: *ígok*)<sup>*</sup> — both of which are pronounced sort of like *doh* — without a *k* sound.

The earliest use<sup>**</sup> of ***doh*** I could find in print was in *Popular History of the Palms and Their Allies* (Berthold Seemann, 1856). About *arenga saccharifera* (the Gomuti palm), it says:

> Like all plants enjoying a wide geographical distribution, this tree
> is distinguished by names as numerous as the languages of the
> countries which claim it as a member of their flora. In Malay, the
> tree is called *Anao* . . . and the horsehair-like material . . . *Iju*
> (*Ejoo* or *Eju*) or *Gomuti*. In Javanese the tree is called *Aren*,
> **the material like horsehair *Duk* (occasionally spelt *Doh*)**, the gossamer-like
> substance *Kawul*, and the sap *Lagen* . . . 
>  <sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Popular_History_of_the_Palms_and_Their_A/_hcaAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22doh%22+%22Popular+History+of+the+Palms+and+Their+Allies%22&pg=RA1-PA63&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

One imagines that Arthur Wynne (1871–1945), the son of a newspaper editor, had a stack of dictionaries lying around. The earliest lexicon I could find containing *doh* was *The Treasury of Botany* (John Lindley, Thomas Moore, 1866):

> DOH. A javanese name for the hosrehair-like fibres of the Gomuti palm,
> *Saguerus saccharifer*
> <sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Treasury_of_Botany/7shJAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22doh%22+%22gomuti%22+%22dictionary%22&pg=PA421&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

(In that dictionary, we can also find another of Arthur Wynne’s plant crosswords from his original puzzle: [NARD](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Treasury_of_Botany_a_Popular_Diction/Vl7JUsoU1fYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nard%22+++%22The+Treasury+of+Botany%22&pg=PA777&printsec=frontcover).)

---

<sub>* [*The History of Java* (Thomas Stamford Raffles, 1817)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_History_of_Java/FOhCAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22java%22+%22aren%22+%22dok%22+%22duk%22&pg=PR101&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

<sup>**</sup> Update: An earlier use of ***doh*** — perhaps informing the 1856 book above — appears in *Wanderings in New South Wales, Batavia, Pedir Coast, Singapore, and China* (George Bennett, 1834):

> About some of the native habitations, that large and elegant palm . .
> . it is the “Anau” of the Sumatrans; was called at this place “Eju”
> and **“Doh”** by the Javanese: it is valued . . . for the black fibres
> [resembling] horsehair.
> <sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wanderings_in_New_South_Wales_Batavia_Pe/KDhCAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22doh%22+%22palm%22&pg=PA414&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

Comment: I found an entry (in Indonesian) about Javanese duk: https://senaraiistilahjawa.kemdikbud.go.id/search/duk 
. I guess the phonetic signs should be /dʊʔ/. It translates to (Malay) ijuk. Also, the Javanese and Malay words seem close enough and may be cognates, and wiktionary says that ijuk was from Proto-Malayo-Polynesian *izuk.